# How to improve the performance of subquery or an alternative to subquery in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, query-optimization, subquery

I am using following query to display records in one of my java swing Application.This query is executing very slow. Is there any way to get the result with improve performance

Is there any way to accomplish the task in smaller time interval.

```
select d.orderid,d.ordername,d.design,isnull(e.OrderQty,0) OrderQty
from 
(
select a.orderid,ordername,design
from filerorn a,ordersNew.dbo.orders b where a.orderid=b.orderid and sub_stage = 'G'
And a.id =@Id
)d
LEFT JOIN
(
select a.OrderId,a.Design,( case when b.ItemId is null 
then a.Qty else 1 end) -isnull(c.Qty,0) OrderQty from 
OrdersNew..ordersDesign a
left join
OrdersNew..OrdersBGTPDesign b
on a.OrderId=b.OrderId and  a.Design
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
=b.Design COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT and a.Sno=b.SNo
left join 
( select a.OrderId,Design,Qty from ExcludeDesign a
left join
dbo.ExcludeDesign_d b
on a.ID=b.ID

)c
on a.OrderId=c.OrderId and a.Design
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
=c.Design COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT and a.Sno=c.Sno

)e
ON d.OrderId=e.OrderId and d.Design COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
=e.Design  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
and d.sno=e.Sno
and d.ItemId=e.ItemId 
order by d.ordername,d.design,d.sno,d.Itemid 
select d.orderid,d.ordername,d.design,isnull(e.OrderQty,0) OrderQty
from 
(
select a.orderid,ordername,design
from filerorn a,ordersNew.dbo.orders b where a.orderid=b.orderid and sub_stage = 'G'
And a.id =@Id
)d
LEFT JOIN
(
select a.OrderId,a.Design,( case when b.ItemId is null 
then a.Qty else 1 end) -isnull(c.Qty,0) OrderQty from 
OrdersNew..ordersDesign a
left join
OrdersNew..OrdersBGTPDesign b
on a.OrderId=b.OrderId and  a.Design
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
=b.Design COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT and a.Sno=b.SNo
left join 
( select a.OrderId,Design,Qty from ExcludeDesign a
left join
dbo.ExcludeDesign_d b
on a.ID=b.ID

)c
on a.OrderId=c.OrderId and a.Design
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
=c.Design COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT and a.Sno=c.Sno

)e
ON d.OrderId=e.OrderId and d.Design COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
=e.Design  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
and d.sno=e.Sno
and d.ItemId=e.ItemId 
order by d.ordername,d.design,d.sno,d.Itemid
```

where orderdesign and orders has million of records

```
Edit
```

**15 %**

```
select a.orderid,ordername,design
from filerorn a,ordersNew.dbo.orders b where a.orderid=b.orderid and sub_stage = 'G'
And a.id =@Id
```

**46%**

```
select a.OrderId,a.Design,( case when b.ItemId is null 
then a.Qty else 1 end) -isnull(c.Qty,0) OrderQty from 
OrdersNew..ordersDesign a
left join
OrdersNew..OrdersBGTPDesign b
on a.OrderId=b.OrderId and  a.Design
```

Comment: Have you used the Query Analyzer to determine where the slowest parts of the query are?

Comment: Why do you specify collation sequences here? `a.Design COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = b.Design COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` Please could you include the schema for your tables, and the default collation sequence for your database?  It is important to know if the fields have different collation sequences, and/or if the database default is different from those fields.  If you are forcing a change in collation sequence mid-query, it's going to be ***very*** expensive.

Comment: yes i did so due to the difference of collation of two tables as it was generating error

Comment: @down voter must explain your point of downvoting the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about making a view and pop some indexes to make it faster for searching. Or make indexes on your tables to make faster search if u dislike doing a view.

Comment: delete your answer i want to delete this question @user1811846